# Python Caesar cipher code flaws

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. This is my 3rd project and I'm facing to some obstacles. Here I have a Caesar cipher project. It seems to do everything I needed it to do that accepts only capital letters, no special characters, no lower case letters, no spaces.

However, I have two issues:

1. It MUST only accept numbers that range from 1 to 26. Unfortunately, it's also accepting numbers that are even higher than 26.
2. Regardless of a key size it only shifts letters by 1 digit. Ideally, it must shift the letters according to entered key size:
   [this is where problem(s) occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8vWP.jpg)

It would be tremendous help if anyone could provide a solution or give suggestions to fix above issues. Thank you so much for your time and attention!

Here is my code:

```
MAX_NUMBER_KEY = 26
def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Please make your selection from the following "E" for encryption or "D" for decryption:')
        mode = raw_input()
        if mode in 'E D'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Error! Please try again and make sure to choose only "E" or "D"!')
def getText():
    while True:
        print('Enter your text that you would like to encrypt or decrypt:')
        text = raw_input()
        if text.isalpha() and text.isupper():
            return text
        else:
            print('Error! No spaces, no special characters or numbers! Please only use letters!')
def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter your number key for "K" (1-%s)' % (MAX_NUMBER_KEY))
        key = int(raw_input().isdigit())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_NUMBER_KEY):
            return key
        else:
           print('Error! Please try again and choose only numbers between (1-26)!')
def getEncryptedMessage(mode, text, key):
    if mode[0] == 'D':
        key = -key
    encrypted = ''
    for each in text:
        if each.isalpha():
            num = ord(each)
            num += key
            if each.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            encrypted += chr(num)
        else:
            encrypted += each
    return encrypted
mode = getMode()
message = getText()
key = getKey()
print('Your encrypted message is:')
print(getEncryptedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: How is CS50 these days?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It's my first time posting a question. Please, review the question again if you can. I made corrections to make it more clear and also uploaded screenshots of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `getKey()`, `raw_input().isdigit()` returns a boolean, so by casting it to an int, you are going to be doing `int(True)` or `int(False)` which is 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Nonetheless, can you review the question again, as I made minor corrections to describe the issues much clearer. I also uploaded screenshots of the issues. Thanks.

Comment: Your code still has this error; this answer is still correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but adding int(True) didn't do what I was looking for. Instead it automatically encrypts the text without asking for users key entry. On the other hand, int(False) puts the process into infinite loop and it keeps running. Thanks anyway.